# Bash prompt customization not working

Tags: bash, iterm

I have installed [Git Aware Prompt](https://github.com/jimeh/git-aware-prompt). I have followed the instructions in the project readme file and customised my prompt in `~./bash_profile` by adding the following lines:

```
export GITAWAREPROMPT=~/.bash/git-aware-prompt
source "${GITAWAREPROMPT}/main.sh"

export PS1="\[\$txtgrn\]$(pwd) \[\$txtcyn\]\$git_branch\[\$txtred\]\$git_dirty\[\$txtrst\] \n\$ "
```

However my cwd is not updated when I cd:

```
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace
$ pwd
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace
$ cd terraxamples/
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace
$ source ~/.bash_profile
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace/terraxamples
```

I have also tried using the env var `$(PWD)` instead of the command `pwd`.

Any idea why this is happening?

I am using iTerm2 in macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

This is what I am getting after re-launching iTerm2:

```
Last login: Mon May 27 12:28:26 on ttys002
/Users/pkaramol
$ cd Workspace/
/Users/pkaramol
$
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Did you relaunch iTerm? Try running `source ~/.bash_profile`. See if either of the two works.

Comment: thanks for the welcome; I have tried both and the problem persists. Check my edit on the question too

Comment: Try running `git branch` and see if there's an initialized Git repository in the directory, with at least one commit.

Comment: There is no `.git` repo on the particular dir but shouldn't `pwd` be working either way?

Comment: Do you mind editing the question and pasting the contents of your `~/.bash_profile`? Something there is causing the previous directory name to get echoed on the terminal. Look for line starting with `echo`.